# Momocs default PCA remove coloured boxes behind points

Tags: r

A R / Momocs learner here.

Currently I'm creating a PCA with some leaf shapes (20+ different populations).

I have created the harmonics and now applying the default (?) PCA graphic:

`lo.f <- efourier(lo, 12)e`
`lo.p <- PCA(lo.f, fac=pop)`
`plot(lo.p, ~pop)`

This produces the default PCA graphic (dots with coloured boxes behind), but the code itself for the graphic is hidden.
I'd like to remove the coloured boxes behind each population (and replace them with something else). It's just too busy with 20+ boxes.
Is it possible to know please where to view the code for the default PCA and remove the coloured boxes bounding each population?

Thanks and apologies such a basic question I am a learner.
M

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, a Momocs authors got back to me.

Basically the answer was instead of using the standard PCA command (listed above in the question) you can apply instead another command-  plot_PCA(lo.p, ~pop, chull=FALSE)

The useful part in my situation being chull=FALSE part, which removed the background shading. There are a number of other options the author advised me to assit in "tweaking' the graphics which I'm currently playing around with.

Thanks all
Michael